# Why does EXCEPT not work? Incorrect Syntax near the Word Except

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, except

```
SELECT SKU
FROM PartProductSupplemental
EXCEPT
SELECT SKU
FROM Inventory
```

Why do I get this error:

> Incorrect Syntax near the Word Except

I check on line and syntax is syntactically correct:

```
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.WorkOrder
EXCEPT
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.Product
```

Comment: Try putting it on one line - it might just be a missing whitespace.

Comment: I know this is flagged correctly, but in the future using SQL 08 as a title could make people think you are talking about an ANSI standard when just reading the title vs a Microsoft product.  More reasonable title would change SQL 08 would be Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  Picky I know:).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your database compatibility mode is probably set to 2000 (80) or earlier.

In Management Studio:

1. Right click on the database name under the "Databases" heading in the Object Explorer
2. In the Properties window that pops up, select "Options" - Compatibility Level is third from the top, on the right.

Comment: Should work in 2005. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: compatability level is SQL Server 2008(80)

Comment: @bizness: 80 is *2000*; 100 means **2008**

Comment: 80 or 2008? 80 - 2000, 90 - 2005, 100 - 2008

Comment: @bizness: that's wrong. It's either "SQL Server 2000(80)" or "SQL Server 2005(90)" or "SQL Server 2008(100)"

Comment: and i guess that solves mystery cuz i cant change compatability cuz im nota llowed.  Thanks guys

Comment: In the Properties window that pops up, select "Options" - Compatibility Level is third from the top, on the right. >> and then do what? cmon people

Answer (score 0):

try using distinct and MINUS just to test.

Except should have worked as well, are the fields of the same type ?

(it works also on 2005, according to documentation and you don't need () on the 2nd phrase).

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following it works fine:

```
with PartProductSupplemental as
(
  SELECT 1 sku
  UNION
  select 2
  UNION
  SELECT 3
  UNION
  select 4
  UNION 
  SELECT 5
),
Inventory as
(
  SELECT 1 sku
  UNION
  select 2
  UNION
  SELECT 3

)

SELECT SKU
FROM PartProductSupplemental
EXCEPT
SELECT SKU
FROM Inventory
```

Are you sure this is actually what you are running?  Is there any sql above that?

Comment: No i swear it just says incorrect syntax near except, and im like but why, and then i look on interwebs and it says this is how we do it

Comment: Lol, i believe you that it throws the error.  Is there any SQL above the section that uses the `EXCEPT`.  Your syntax is valid, so something else is up.

Comment: SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM(SELECT SKU
    FROM PartProductSupplemental

    EXCEPT

    SELECT SKU
    FROM Inventory
)

Comment: I tested on 2005 with a db set to compatibility 80 -- worked fine for me, no errors

Comment: I think the real problem has to do with his `SELECT COUNT FROM (SubQusery)` but oh well